# This workspace is not eligible for the next generation Slack platform

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am trying to create a slack app, and learn more about the slack api.
while following the [quick start](https://api.slack.com/automation/quickstart). I ran into this error after entering my authorization ticket into my slack workspace

`This workspace is not eligible for the next generation Slack platform.`

How to fix this

Comment: Have you contacted Slack?

Comment: No, thought this was a system problem.